# XML Feed Won't Validate

Tags: xml, validation, rss, feed

I can not figure out why my feed won't validate.  feedvalidator.org gives me an error of an invalid token, but it shows the invalid token simply in the name of a particular file, and everything is correct.  Am I Missing something here?

http://316apps.com/cursos/cursosvideos.xml

UPDATE:  It was an error with wrong type quotation marks, and has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enclosing your attribute values with 7 bit ascii quotes.

Comment: I had up-voted your answer, and am not sure why someone would down vote it.  Your answer was correct, and my feed has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your feed does validate. Ignore the warning, and you can safely remove the atom link. It's not part of the RSS format, it's something the validator developers want you to do, they really shouldn't have put that in the validator at all.

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2F316apps.com%2Fcursos%2Fcursosvideos.xml